# After INSERT Trigger do insert table a_temp and delete from table a_temp

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have two table **employees** and **employees_audit**, I created a trigger after insert where it will **insert data to employees_audit** and then **delete data from table employees**

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
        employeeNumber INT NOT NULL,
        lastname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    );

CREATE TABLE employees_audit (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    employeeNumber INT NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    changedat DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    action VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

And this is the trigger

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `test`
AFTER INSERT ON `employee` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
insert into employees_audit(employeeNumber,lastname,changedat,action) values(NEW.employeeNumber,NEW.lastname,CURDATE(),'wew'); delete from employee; 
END
```

But when I insert data on table employee i got this error

```
#1442 - Can't update table 'employee' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

How to create a trigger insert event that delete data on table that has the trigger?

Comment: You want to delete employees table after inserting into audit table, then why you need employees table, insert directly into audit? No need to trigger.

Comment: I have been asked to do smthing like that

Comment: Please who downvote this question give a reason, so I know my mistake Thx!

Comment: If "I have been asked to do smthing like that", then something is wrong; database design/requirement/your understanding. You need to look for towards this aspect also, as fundamentally you are doing it wrong.

Comment: yeah, i feel this is weird too.. but still, I am asking this hoping to get a solution :)

Comment: You could insert employeenumber to a work table and then use this to delete from employee at a convenient time.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. If you are deleting all the data from employee table why do you need that table. Insert directly into employees_audit.

Comment: I have been asked to do smthing like that

Comment: You cannot DELETE rows in the table that activated trigger. You can write logic in your application without using trigger